# Virtual box error - Kernel Driver not installed

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, intel

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu for the first time and I am trying to install and use virtual box. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded the deb package from the virtual-box website and installed the software. Then I tried to import a virtual machine I was using on a mac.

```
I got the following error.

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'
```

Then I ran the command /sbin/vboxconfig as root. I also turned off the UEFI from boot menu. (secure boot). Then I got the following error message.

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: You must sign these kernel modules before using VirtualBox:
  vboxdrv vboxnetflt vboxnetadp
See the documenatation for your Linux distribution..
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: Failed to enroll secure boot key..
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Any help on how to fix the error?

Comment: Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.